Tensorboard ERROR: Failed to capture profile: empty trace result on tensorflow 2.10.1 on windows
friends, Help me to resolve this problem please
monitor="val_accuracy"
callbacks=[TensorBoard(get_run_logdir(),profile_batch = '0,{}'.format(batch_size),histogram_freq=1),
           ModelCheckpoint("model.h5",save_weights_only=True,monitor=monitor),
           ReduceLROnPlateau(patience=1,factor=0.5,monitor=monitor),
           EarlyStopping(patience=10,monitor=monitor)]

I set url in tensorboard profile to localhost:6009 while training my model in conda env with jupyter lab. It says Failed to capture profile: empty trace result
I use tensorflow 2.10.1 on windows with conda env
tensorboard
profiler window
Here is my env modules
absl-py==1.4.0
aggdraw==1.3.18.post0
alembic==1.13.2
anyio==4.4.0
argon2-cffi==23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
arrow==1.3.0
asttokens==2.4.1
astunparse==1.6.3
async-lru==2.0.4
attrs==23.2.0
Babel==2.15.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
bleach==6.1.0
cachetools==5.3.3
catboost==1.2.5
certifi==2024.6.2
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
cloudpickle==3.0.0
colorama==0.4.6
colorlog==6.8.2
comm==0.2.2
contourpy==1.2.1
cycler==0.12.1
debugpy==1.8.2
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
dill==0.3.8
dm-tree==0.1.8
docstring_parser==0.16
etils==1.7.0
exceptiongroup==1.2.1
executing==2.0.1
fastjsonschema==2.20.0
flatbuffers==24.3.25
fonttools==4.53.0
fqdn==1.5.1
fsspec==2024.6.0
gast==0.4.0
google-auth==2.30.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.63.2
graphviz==0.20.3
greenlet==3.0.3
grpcio==1.64.1
gviz-api==1.10.0
h11==0.14.0
h5py==3.11.0
httpcore==1.0.5
httpx==0.27.0
idna==3.7
immutabledict==4.2.0
importlib_resources==6.4.0
ipykernel==6.29.4
ipython==8.25.0
ipywidgets==8.1.3
isoduration==20.11.0
jedi==0.19.1
Jinja2==3.1.4
joblib==1.4.2
json5==0.9.25
jsonpointer==3.0.0
jsonschema==4.22.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-console==6.6.3
jupyter-events==0.10.0
jupyter-lsp==2.2.5
jupyter_client==8.6.2
jupyter_core==5.7.2
jupyter_server==2.14.1
jupyter_server_terminals==0.5.3
jupyterlab==4.2.3
jupyterlab_pygments==0.3.0
jupyterlab_server==2.27.2
jupyterlab_widgets==3.0.11
keras==2.10.0
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.4.5
libclang==18.1.1
lightgbm==4.4.0
Mako==1.3.5
Markdown==3.6
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
matplotlib==3.9.0
matplotlib-inline==0.1.7
mdurl==0.1.2
mistune==3.0.2
ml-dtypes==0.3.2
namex==0.0.8
nbclient==0.10.0
nbconvert==7.16.4
nbformat==5.10.4
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
notebook==7.2.1
notebook_shim==0.2.4
numpy==1.26.4
oauthlib==3.2.2
openfe==0.0.12
opt-einsum==3.3.0
optree==0.11.0
optuna==3.6.1
overrides==7.7.0
packaging==24.1
pandas==2.2.2
pandocfilters==1.5.1
parso==0.8.4
pillow==10.3.0
platformdirs==4.2.2
plotly==5.22.0
prometheus_client==0.20.0
promise==2.3
prompt_toolkit==3.0.47
protobuf==3.19.6
psutil==6.0.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pyarrow==16.1.0
pyasn1==0.6.0
pyasn1_modules==0.4.0
pycparser==2.22
Pygments==2.18.0
pyparsing==3.1.2
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-json-logger==2.0.7
pytz==2024.1
pywin32==306
pywinpty==2.0.13
PyYAML==6.0.1
pyzmq==26.0.3
qtconsole==5.5.2
QtPy==2.4.1
referencing==0.35.1
requests==2.32.3
requests-oauthlib==2.0.0
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rfc3986-validator==0.1.1
rich==13.7.1
rpds-py==0.18.1
rsa==4.9
scikit-learn==1.5.0
scipy==1.14.0
Send2Trash==1.8.3
simple_parsing==0.1.5
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.1
soupsieve==2.5
SQLAlchemy==2.0.31
stack-data==0.6.3
tenacity==8.4.2
tensorboard==2.10.1
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorboard_plugin_profile==2.15.1
tensorflow==2.10.1
tensorflow-addons==0.18.0
tensorflow-datasets==4.6.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.10.0
tensorflow-hub==0.12.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
tensorflow-metadata==1.8.0
tensorflow-model-optimization==0.7.0
tensorflow-probability==0.18.0
tensorflow_intel==2.10.0
termcolor==2.4.0
terminado==0.18.1
threadpoolctl==3.5.0
tinycss2==1.3.0
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
tornado==6.4.1
tqdm==4.66.4
traitlets==5.14.3
typeguard==4.3.0
types-python-dateutil==2.9.0.20240316
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.1
uri-template==1.3.0
urllib3==2.2.2
visualkeras==0.0.2
wcwidth==0.2.13
webcolors==24.6.0
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.8.0
Werkzeug==3.0.3
widgetsnbextension==4.0.11
wrapt==1.16.0
zipp==3.19.2

I tried installing tensorboard_plugin_profile==2.15.1
I tried setting localhost:6010
I tried changing batch size TensorBoard(get_run_logdir(),profile_batch = '0,{}'.format(batch_size),histogram_freq=1),

Hi @Nikson,It appears you're facing a problem with TensorBoard's profiling features, specifically the error message "Failed to capture profile: empty trace result." This issue can stem from various factors, such as configuration problems or mismatches between TensorBoard and TensorFlow versions.Make sure that the versions of TensorBoard and the TensorBoard Profiler plugin you are using are compatible with TensorFlow 2.10.1. Based on your environment, you have TensorBoard version 2.10.1 and TensorBoard Profiler plugin version 2.15.1, which should be compatible with TensorFlow 2.10.1.
